# Metdata and Synching Document Libraries with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, sync

We are trying to move away from folders but in some instances, that means flattening a structure with thousands of documents. What would you suggest to a user who 'Syncs' their document library to File Explorer? How does metadata work in your advantage when it's outside SharePoint document library view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the best of both worlds?

**First**, you don't have to *actually* flatten your folder structure to give your SharePoint views the *appearance* of a flat structure.  In the view settings of all of your metadata-driven views, set the **Folders** option to `Show all items without folders` (see screenshot).  This has the effect of allowing this View to ignore the fact that folders exist and simply show all files in the library that meet your filtering/grouping settings.

[image]

This gives you the advantage that SharePoint users can use and see metadata-driven views, but the folders can still exist behind the scenes so that users who are synchronizing with Explorer, can still have their precious folders.

**Second**, if your users are disciplined in completing the metadata to make your Views accurate, you could implement a set of business rules in a **Flow** in **Power Automate** so that when users upload new files to the library and enter the appropriate metadata, the Flow could move that file to the "best" Folder.  The user in SharePoint won't care what folder it was moved to, but the users using Explorer will be happy.

**Third**, if some users will be uploading files through Explorer, you could implement a specific View in SharePoint (which wold also have the `Show all items without folders` option configured) to list all files that are missing the necessary metadata, so the user (or designated admin) can "fix" the files that were uploaded by an Explorer user.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive sync client does not (today) support metadata in Windows Explorer view -- you can still set metadata in the document properties via a client application (such as Word). Any metadata filtering isn't applicable to the sync process.